# Why not do all cpu intensive operation on main thread - using co-routines?

Tags: android, multithreading, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I know we should not be doing this, and have pretty much an idea of why's.

Wanted to understand it in detail and is looking for an explanation in detail -

As co-routines are non-blocking, I believe IO or CPU-intensive operations can be done on the main thread as well - i.e. - launching co-routines on Main Dispatcher, and android will not complain about (skipped .. frames or intensive work on the Main thread), and no worry of ANR's.

My question is why do we prefer non-UI dispatchers to launch co-routines for IO and CPU-intensive work  -

To

- Use threads pools and achieve parallelism? - But isn't co-routines a concurrent model and does not achieve parallelism, or it does and is both and implemented in a different way in kotlin.

Or, is there a different reason. I understand - in other threading models like RxJava, etc.. it's required to do it in a different thread, as the threads are blocking.

For example -

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      doSomeHeavyOp() // blocks the main thread for 8 sec, can give ANR
      viewModel.fetchDataFromServer()
    }
    private fun doSomeHeavyOp(){ // blocks the main thread
      Thread.sleep(8000) // sleep for 8 secs
    }
}
```

But, If I use co-routines

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      lifecycleScope.launch { // launches co-routine on main-thread
        doSomeHeavyOp()
      }
      viewModel.fetchDataFromServer() // this will be executed immediately -  as in sequentially
    }
    private suspend fun doSomeHeavyOp(){ // does-not block the main thread
       delay(8000) // suspend for 8 secs
    }
}
```

The second example, won't block the main/ui thread, hence no ANR and heavy computation happens on UI thread concurrently.

Comment: One reason would be that most processors have multiple cores.

Comment: @MartinJames - yes, so the main reason of putting it in others dispatchers to makes use of different cores and parallelism. But, same can be achieved from main thread as well without blocking the main-thread? - and android will never complain of skipped frames or will throw an ANR?

Comment: I believe - even though you can achieve concurrency on a single main thread without blocking  using coroutines, if you'll overload it with work, your application will skip frames. Therefore, you always want to offload long-running work to background dispatchers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood what does it mean that coroutines do not block. They don't make every blocking code magically non-blocking. If you execute a blocking I/O operation inside a coroutine, it will still block the thread. If you perform CPU-intensive calculations inside a coroutine, you will still occupy some thread and it won't be able to do anything else.

Coroutines give us a possibility to temporarily stop execution of our code to wait for something without blocking the thread. This is called suspending to distinguish it from blocking. Inside coroutines you can suspend, but if you block then you still block as normal.

Let's see this example:

```
suspend fun runOnMainThread() {
    // 1
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // 2
    }
    // 3
}
```

We execute this function from the main thread. We have to wait for IO operation before we can proceed to `3`, so normally it would mean the main thread is blocked while waiting. In our case the execution of this function is suspended and the main thread is free to do something else while waiting for IO. Something like this would be impossible without coroutines and without asynchronous operations.

While using coroutines we should try to suspend instead of blocking whenever possible. If we use IO library that provides an API that does not block, but suspend, then we can do exactly what you said - use this IO library normally inside the main dispatcher. But as long as we use traditional blocking operations, we should switch to IO dispatcher.

Comment: I was thinking in terms of concurrency, where time-slicing happens and considering co-routine is a concurrency model, i was thinking it might work. I may be totally wrong, haven't tested it yet.

Consider this example 

fun doheavyComp(){
  // scope uses main dispatcher
  scope.launch(){ // some cpu-intensive work }
  // any code here is executed immediately 
}

Comment: Consider this example 
**fun doheavyComp(){ 
// scope uses main dispatcher 
scope.launch(){ // some cpu-intensive work } 
// any code here is executed immediately 
}** 

Let's say above function gets called in an activity, the scope is non-blocking, and next line will be executed immediately.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your example right. If you mean that `doheavyComp()` is executed on the main thread and `scope` uses `Dispatchers.Main`, so also the main thread then these two parts of code (inside `launch()` and below it) can't run in parallel. Yes, code below `launch()` will be executed immediately, but code inside `launch()` will be not. If you put `Thread.sleep()` below `launch()`, you will see that your cpu-intensive stuff can't even start until the other code finishes. Coroutines have to cooperate between each other to free threads for other coroutines.

Comment: I agree, with you. What, if i donot put Thread.sleep(), but put an delay() instead which will suspend() - instead of blocking the main-thread. Say, i start all co-routines on main-thread, co-routines will suspend and use time-slicing and copy stack-frame and all.. but it still won't block the main thread and give me an ANR? or it will? My question  - why do we dispatch these heavy comp work in default or io thread? is it to make use of pool threads  - and kotlin co-routine, the way it's written can be parallel and not-single threaded, like java-script?

Comment: Edited my question and added an example for clarity.

Comment: If you use `delay()` then everything will be fine, because it does not block, but suspends. `Thread.sleep()` blocks, typical IO operations block, CPU-intensive code blocks (occupies the thread), so all of these will make the application unresponsive (ANR) if run in the main thread - no matter if you use coroutines or not. However, suspending in the main thread/dispatcher does not block the main thread and therefore it does not make the application unresponsive.

Comment: That's correct - and i understand what sleep does and how CPU-intensive or IO operations blocks any thread.
Suspending any operation in the main thread/dispatcher won't block and it won't make the application unresponsive. 
Then, the only reason i see to give Default/IO dispatcher to achieve parallelism/concurrency in other thread and make use of available cores - less executon time etc..
That being said - can we conclude that, any operation suspended on main/ui thread won't make the application unresponsive in general - it will be like concurrency on single-thread/ui without blocking.

Comment: Yes, assuming that a suspend function is implemented correctly (so it never blocks internally, only suspends) and it is not CPU-intensive, it is safe to invoke it from the main dispatcher. Even if it is in fact an IO operation. There are libraries like e.g. `ktor-client` that let you perform networking, etc. by suspending and not blocking. You can use them normally. Most of IO APIs/libs available are not suspending, but blocking (or they are async), so you should not use them from the main dispatcher.

Comment: yes, thanks. I am aware of these, the only reason i posted this question to understand if i am missing some point from my end.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in saying that it won't block the main/ui thread. but still it will run on main thread. Main thread is already busy with plenty of things. Most important one being rendering UI continuously at some refresh rate(maybe 50 times a second).

so why add more load to it? when you have other dispatchers and cores.

Also android does complain about skipped frames if you do such kind of work on main thread. search for this in android logcat "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."